# solution for GPS and Maps Offline android

Tags: android, gps, maps, offline

I have a problem and need help 
is it possible to know the coordinates of the GPS offline? and appear in the offline maps too?? 
please clue me confused

Comment: In Offline mode you can get only `LastKnownLocation` not the latest one.

Comment: @Kedarnath how ???
What the harness cache?? and offline maps created manually and stored in the application?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)

Comment: You can get your location's latitude and longitude coordinates via GPS when offline. The GPS receiver requires no internet or telephone data connection, only a clear view of the sky.

Comment: @NickT,, okey, but I did not try my internet connection device still shows 00 what wrong?
then later to appear in the offline maps like what? 
I am still confused? I am not sure that this could be accurate data it receives